# Display custom template in home page Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, php

My problem is that i cant display some custom (created by me) template in home page. Read a lot but without success. I've tried to display it in content from backend in Magento like

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/list2.phtml"}}
```

Comment: what is the result of this?

Comment: Nothing, just blank div

Comment: Just Cross check File Location and Catgory ID once

Comment: /app/design/frontend/custom_theme/default/template/catalog/product/list2.phtml 
This is location of file and custom theme is enabled
Top books (ID: 5)
This is the ID of the category, nothing wrong

Comment: is the catalog/product_list block type whitelisted in the security settings (system/permissions/blocks)?

Comment: Yes @EnzoPerrotta You are Correct Check this

Comment: @EnzoPerrotta That was the trick thanks a lot dude : D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitelist the catalog/product_list block type in the security settings (system/permissions/blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `catalog/product_list` block was added to the white list of allowed blocks.

Magento 1.9.2.2 introduced a white list of allowed block types. If a block was added to a CMS page or to a static block through a block code (for example: `{{block type="catalog/product_list"`), and the block is not on the white list, it will not be displayed on frontend.

The white list of allowed blocks can be found under **System -> Permissions -> Blocks**

The permission system normally only allows a reduced number of blocks:

```
core/template
catalog/product_new
```

So you can manually add blocks to the white list. For example, you can add these blocks:

```
cms/block
catalog/product_list
```